# Jersey name for World Peace

Tags: basketball, uniform

I am new to watching the NBA. I saw the name World Peace as #15 for the Lakers. However, I saw highlights of the same player, number, and team with the name Artest. Why these names? What is the history behind these names?

Answer (score 9):

Ron Artest changed his name to Metta World Peace in 2011.

"[Changing my name was meant to inspire and bring youth together all around the world.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ron_artest#Personal_life)"

Comment: Quite ironic given his style of play on the court

Answer (score 2):

He legally changed his name from to Metta World Peace in September 2011 ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metta_World_Peace)).

After the 2013-14 NBA season, he played in China for a few months. When he first moved there, he announced that he would rename himself "The Panda's Friend" ([CBS Sports](http://www.cbssports.com/nba/eye-on-basketball/24651716/metta-world-peace-to-change-name-to-panda-friend)). However, his name on his Chinese jersey remained Metta World Peace (or more precisely 慈世平, which is a three word/character abbreviation of his full Chinese name 慈善·世界和平).

In March 2015 he moved to play in Italy. In [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4TLECsmUGqc) of some his highlights while in Italy, I see that the name on his Italian jersey is "The Panda's Friend". However the commentators seem to call him "Metta World Peace".

So, I do not know what his legal name actually is now.